# Transfering btc from blockchain to electrum wallet, still unconfirmed

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

i transferred btc from blockchain to electrum wallet. it has like 132 confirmations but on blockchain it's still Pending: 0/3 Confirmations Status. I paid fee and everything. Is this something normal or Is there anything happening? this is my first post here. thanks much

Comment: where does it have 132 confirmations then?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a Phishing attack going on with electrum. Did you make sure you downloaded electrum from the official site? Also with wich electrum servers did your electrum wallet connect? Maybe one spreading false information to trick you into their fishing attack